# (Re)Using Mongo Debezium Offset , after configuration change

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Let's say, I have a Debezium Mongo Source Connector, and if create a source config by mentioning one collection
`sample_mflix.movies` , the resumeToken will be stored, so when the connector restarts it fetches resume_token from `connect-offset` and start from there.

but if I changed the number of collections, the conig changes,  then is there a way to use the same offset for the first collection, while starting from beginning from second one. ?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find any configurable approach.

The Debezium Connector works in two phases

1. Take an Initial Snapshot
2. Read new mutations from oplog

So, In order to accommodate the addition of a new collection, I had to change the way Debezium stores offset,
Currently, they store at the Replica Set level.
I changed the code to mark for which all collections and snapshot has been taken. Since a newly added collection will not have that mark, a snapshot will be taken for that collection, once all collections have their snapshot till the current time, now they start reading from Oplog and send mutations to respective collections.